# Could not create an Azure VM "This virtual machine requires a subscription without any spending limit or temporary payment method set."

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a new Azure VM as I usually do (same subscription and same configuration) but I'm getting an error saying:

> This virtual machine requires a subscription without any spending
> limit or temporary payment method set. Use a different subscription or
> update your subscription (requires account administrator privileges)
> at [Account Center](https://account.windowsazure.com) to continue.

[image]

Do you have an explanation or do you know if there is any restriction (or any other change) from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Are you the Global Admin? do you have a new billing Admin? this error happens when you need a new payment method or have updated the payment method recently. Or you have added a spending limit. follow the link provided for instructions to check each. **Cost Management + Billing** should have a section called **Usage + charges**. first check the Spending Limit and remove if you dont need it. then check the "Payment methods" and make sure there is not any temporary payment information.

you may have been using credits that have run out.

contact support if you have any billing issues or just to get more details through a support ticket in the azure portal.

Comment: No I'm not the Global Admin and I was always able to create VMs.

Comment: contact your Global admin with the provided information and they can address the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think its an Azure issue. I am getting the same error message, I am a global admin and I have plenty of credit. I just tried to create a SQL Database and it worked fine. Microsoft have been making changes at the back end and may of screwed up

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to choose a 22H2 Windows image instead of a 23H2 Windows image to prevent the message "This virtual machine requires a subscription without any spending limit."

For example, the message disappeared when I chose images ...

> Windows 11 Pro, version **22H2** - x64 Gen2, or

> Windows 11 Enterprise, version **22H2** - x64 Gen2

... instead of images ...

> Windows 11 Pro, version **23H2** - x64 Gen2, or

> Windows 11 Enterprise, version **23H2** - x64 Gen2

---

In a Microsoft answers thread titled [How to solve this subscription spending limit issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1305434/how-to-solve-this-subscription-spending-limit-issu), someone reported that choosing Windows Server 2022 instead of Windows Server 2016 helped, although I do not know if that is still true.